# set of continuous functions to continuous functions: is $R$ complete?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

[image]

Hi, I can do part (i) and (ii) but have trouble understanding part (iii). I can't intutively feel what the map R does. It takes continuous function to continuous function? How would I start the proof?

Thanks.

Comment: It would help to know of this map $R$ were an isometry...

Answer (score 1):

By construction, any function  in the image of $R$ can be extended to a function in $C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$. Given a Cauchy sequence in the image of $R$, extend all its elements, and obtain a Cauchy sequence in $C([0,1],\mathbb{R}),$ which is a complete metric space. Reduce the limit function back to $(0,1)$, and get a limit to the initial sequence.